# NodeInvocationException: Attempt to connect to Node timed out

Tags: angularjs, node.js, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have created a new angular project in Visual Studio 2017 in my work laptop, I'm getting the Node invocation exception error when I run the program.
I had the same issue in my home laptop but it was resolved after I installed the latest version of node.js. 
I have installed the same nodejs version in my work laptop but the issue still persists. when I run the node - v command in my work laptop instead of the version number I'm getting a different name.

Could someone please help with this.

[Exception message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnhQv.jpg)[Node and NPM version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VprMS.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that we have CA node installed in my office laptop so it was showing 2 nodes. I updated the environment variable path to list the node.js in up front so it takes the priority, this issue has been resolved now.