# aspnetcore with angular error NodeInvocationException: The Node invocation timed out after 60000ms

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, angular-universal, aspnetcoretemplatepack

i'm using `yo generator-aspnetcore-spa`
once i run the app i got problem

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> NodeInvocationException: The Node invocation timed out after 60000ms.
>   You can change the timeout duration by setting the
>   InvocationTimeoutMilliseconds property on NodeServicesOptions.
>
> The first debugging step is to ensure that your Node.js function
>   always invokes the supplied callback (or throws an exception
>   synchronously), even if it encounters an error. Otherwise, the .NET
>   code has no way to know that it is finished or has failed.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance+d__13.MoveNext()
>
> NodeInvocationException: The Node invocation timed out after 60000ms. 
>   You can change the timeout duration by setting the
>   InvocationTimeoutMilliseconds property on NodeServicesOptions. The
>   first debugging step is to ensure that your Node.js function always
>   invokes the supplied callback (or throws an exception synchronously),
>   even if it encounters an error. Otherwise, the .NET code has no way to
>   know that it is finished or has failed.

and red color on this line

> AspNetCore._Views_Home_Index_cshtml+d__31.MoveNext() in
>   Index.cshtml
>   +
>       ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";

this is how my package.json look like

```
{
  "name": "WebApplicationBasic",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.38",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^2.0.6",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.29",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "ng-snotify": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-cookie": "^1.0.0",
    "preboot": "^4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.17.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  }
}
```

my app was work fine and i don't no what is the reason of this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was in aspnet-prerendering module 
it looks like this in View>>Home>>Index.csHtml

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

Then when i removed it the app works fine

```
<app>Loading...</app>
```

but there is no server-side rendering of course by this 
so when i finished from developing the app i write this command in root directory of my project

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
webpack
```

and restored the

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

and it works as it should be :)

Comment: I have the same problem, but this doesn't resolve the issue. The problem is that I get this error on another computer when my repo is cloned. On the computer where project is created it works fine.

Comment: Where do we need to add these webpack commands, any specific file?

Answer (score 6):

We host our site in Azure and the solution for me was to add this config key/value to the Application settings.

Key: WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION 

Value: 6.9.1

I suppose you could also add it to your appsetting.json or web.config as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  It might be an issue with the local version of node.

I set my local nodejs version to 5.4.3 and was able to get the app running, try checking your node version using this on your console/terminal:

```
node -v
```

I think removing the prerendering tag then running webpack might still be excluding that module from server-side prerendering, so hopefully a newer node version can help run the app as expected without code changes.

Also there's a similar issue here :
[NodeInvocationException: Attempt to connect to Node timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938067/nodeinvocationexception-attempt-to-connect-to-node-timed-out)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to this question, but I had the same issue and came here.

I have Windows HPC pack installed, and that means the node.exe on my PATH was the [Windows HPC node command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947691(v=ws.11).aspx) rather than the third-party NodeJS node.exe

This meant I got the timeout as it was running the HPC node command instead of using NodeJS to run webpack. To fix, I removed the path from the PATH environment variable and restarted Visual Studio. I could have reordered the paths, or renamed one of the node.exe, but I don't use the HPC commands from the command line, only from code.

Discussion of the conflict in NodeJS https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7773